# Pesquisa não reconhece arquivo .zip como arquivo válido dentro de uma pasta

Tags: c#

Fiz essa rotina para deletar pastas vazias, sem arquivos dentro.

```
foreach(var folder in folder_new)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                if (Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length == 0)
                    {
                       Directory.Delete(folder, true);
                    }
             }
          }
```

Até aí beleza, exceto um problema. Quando tenho uma pasta apenas com um arquivo `.zip` dentro, ele deleta o folder, por achar que o folder está vazio. Como eu contorno isso?

Ex: Tenho essa árvore de pastas:

```
web\ws\tiss\v3\02\00
```

E dentro da pasta `00`, tenho o arquivo `TISS.zip`. A pasta ws e todo seu conteúdo(subfolders) é deletada.

```
string[] files_new = Directory.GetFiles(path_files, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string[] folder_new = Directory.GetDirectories(path_files, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Fiz essa função e continua a deletar pastas e subpasta, se na última houver apenas um arquivo `.zip`.

```
private void processaDiretorio(string inicio)
{
   foreach(var diretorio in Directory.GetDirectories(inicio))
   {
       processaDiretorio(diretorio);
       if (Directory.GetFiles(diretorio).Length == 0 &&
           Directory.GetDirectories(diretorio).Length == 0)
       {
           Directory.Delete(diretorio, false);
        }
   }
}
```

Mudei o método para esse aqui, usando `DirectoryInfo` e mesmo assim não consigo pegar arquivo `.zip` nas pastas.

```
private void processaDiretorio(string inicio)
        {

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(inicio);

            foreach (var fi in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                processaDiretorio(fi.FullName);

                if (fi.GetFiles().Length == 0 && fi.GetDirectories().Length == 0)
                {
                    fi.Delete();
                }
            }
}
```

Porém usando essa abordagem(`DirectoryInfo`), eu consigo pegar arquivos `.zip` dentro.

```
foreach(var file in new DirectoryInfo(path_files).GetFiles())
{ 
    string s = file.Name;
}
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `folder_new`?

Comment: u@rubStackOverflow, Uma lista de diretórios. Todos os diretórios a partir de uma pasta base. Fiz uma edição no post original.

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de C#, mas pelo que notei está usando `Directory`, me diga o que acontece se usar `DirectoryInfo`, assim: `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MinhaPasta");


            Console.WriteLine("Search pattern AllDirectories returns:");
            foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            }`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, bom dia. Tive que pausar essa parte para resolver um problema na empresa e logo que eu voltar, vou testar o que você me passou por comentário. Só mais um tempinho.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, realmente você praticamente disse tudo. Deveria usar a classe DirectoryInfo e não a Directory. Só preciso agora melhorar meu método usando o DirectoryInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço muito de C#, mas na documentação o `Directory.GetDirectories` não tinha parâmetros, porém os parâmetros que citou direcionaram pra documentação do `DirectoryInfo`, tente fazer isto:

```
private void processaDiretorio(string inicio)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(inicio);

    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetDirectories())
    {
         processaDiretorio(fi.FullName);

         if (fi.GetFiles().Length == 0 && fi.GetDirectories().Length == 0) {
               fi.Delete();
         }
    }
}
```

Veja um teste simples, crie um aplicação Console e cole o seguinte conteudo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            processaDiretorio("C:\\test\\");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void processaDiretorio(string inicio)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(inicio);

            foreach (var fi in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                 int tf = fi.GetFiles().Length;
                 int tp = fi.GetDirectories().Length;

                 Console.WriteLine("Delete: {0}, Total arquivos: {1}, total pastas: {2}", fi.FullName, tf.ToString(), tp.ToString());
                 processaDiretorio(fi.FullName);

                 if (fi.GetFiles().Length == 0 && fi.GetDirectories().Length == 0)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Deleteing {0}...", fi.FullName);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("No delete {0}", fi.FullName);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se faço isso, acho qualquer arquivo .zip na pasta: `foreach(var file in new DirectoryInfo(path_files).GetFiles()) { }`. Mas da forma como você respondeu, eu não acho arquivo `.zip` dentro das pastas.

Comment: @pnet vou testar assim que possivel e te dou um feedback

Comment: Fiz de várias formas e não consegui ainda, unir o que tá funcionando e deletar a pasta vazia e poupar a pasta com arquivos.

Comment: @pnet realmente não sei o porque isto ocorre, veja eu postei um código de exemplo completo na resposta, testa ele por favor.